Timeline of a long straddle
Is the following an accurate account of a long straddle?
Initially, I am delta neutral. Then, say, the price of the underlying increases by 1. The call now has a delta of, say, 0.7. To reset delta-neutrality, I short-sell 70 shares of underlying. Then, the price of the underlying decreases by 1. The put now has a delta of -0.6. As such, I buy back 60 shares of the underlying each of which I had previously sold for 1 dollar higher. Hence, I make a profit. And the role of delta-neutrality was to ensure that movements in the price of the call and put did not offset this small profit.
Then, the price of the underlying jumps by 40. Due to the convexity of the call payoff function, the call appreciates more than the 10 share short position loses. Also, my 60 share long position appreciates. Also, suppose the sum of my gains from the long position and the appreciation of the call - loss from the short > premium I paid for call + premium I paid for put. I thus close the position profitably.
Is all this sound?

Didn't read the second paragraph but when you hedge you should make sure that the call and put deltas offset each other and you are not looking at each in isolation.
